# Form Onsubmit() is not getting triggered on clicking submit button (reactJs, Formik, Yup)

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am making a Login Form for my Project but when i tried validation using formik and Yup, onsubmit is not working in any condition. 
i tried removing any validation and also tried following all validation rules but still nothing seems to be working...

here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const LoginSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string()
        .email('Invalid email')
        .required('Required'),
    password: Yup.string()
        .min(6, 'Password has to be atleast 6 characters long')
        .required('Required')
});


const SingIn = ({ createAccount }) => {
    return (
        <div className="">

            <div className="text-2xl m-4 font-medium text-center lg:text-4xl">Sign in</div>

            <Formik
                initialValues={{
                    email: '',
                    password: '',
                }}
                validationSchema={LoginSchema}
                // validator={() => ({})}
                onSubmit={values => {
                    // same shape as initial values
                    alert(values);
                    console.log('here')
                }}
            >
                {({ errors, touched }) => (
                    <Form>
                        <div className={`w-full flex flex-col my-4`}>
                            <label className="uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-600 text-xs font-semibold mb-2 lg:text-2xl">Email</label>
                            <Field required name="email" type="email" className="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-800 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500 lg:text-3xl" />
                            {errors.email && touched.email ? <div>{errors.email}</div> : null}
                        </div>

                        <div className={`w-full flex flex-col my-4`}>
                            <label className="uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-600 text-xs font-semibold mb-2 lg:text-2xl">Password</label>
                            <Field required name="password" type="password" className="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-800 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500 lg:text-3xl" />
                            {errors.password && touched.password ? <div>{errors.password}</div> : null}
                        </div>

                        <div className="w-full flex justify-between items-center mb-4 mt-10">
                            <button className="text-blue-600 font-semibold" onClick={createAccount}>Create Account</button>
                            <button type="submit" className="px-5 py-2 bg-blue-600 shadow-md hover:shadow-2xl rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-800 inline-flex justify-center items-center">
                                <span className="text-white font-semibold">Login</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </Form>
                )}

            </Formik>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SingIn;
```

i tried bunch of stuff, nothing seeems to be working... YELP!!

EDIT(SOLVED): 
Actually there's no problem with the code, the problem is that this sign in window is modal and it has a backgournd, on which i have given a onClick function to close the modal, i worked around that modal. Thanks :)

Comment: you want to trigger the onSubmit function right?

Comment: yes, exactly.. can you please help me out, i am so stuck.

Comment: This code fires onSubmit for me. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kketky . But it fires the function on both the buttons. If you need to fire different functions for buttons let me know

Comment: The other button for "create account" works just fine for me but the login button doesnt

Comment: i got it ....Actually there's no problem with the code, the problem is that this sign in window is modal and it has a backgournd, on which i have given a onClick function to close the modal, i worked around that modal. Thanks :)

Comment: happy to help :)